# How to get a polyline's extent in api 4.15?

Tags: polyline, arcgis-js-api, extent

I had new a polyline using paths,then I try to use polyline.extent to get extent,it return null.

`var extent = polyline.extent;`

Answer (score 1):

I had found the reason,because i never new a Polyline.

```
var polyline = {
      type: "polyline", 
      paths: positions
    };
var polylineGraphic = new Graphic({
      geometry: polyline)}
```

It should like this:

```
var polyline = new Polyline({
      type: "polyline", // autocasts as new Polyline()
      paths: positions
    });
```